# Can I use a dead Weller soldering station?

Tags: soldering

I have only the pencil of a Weller soldering station

[image]

Can I use it without the station? I tried to use it directly with 220V but it's not working.

In the pencil it says 50W/24V. I tried with 32V but nothing happened.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: "I tried to use it directely with 220v but it's not working." nor will it likely work on the intended supply ever again, unless you managed to fail to actually make connection to the heater or any other key parts.  Have you considered doing a web search for the pinout or wiring diagram?

Comment: If it was working before, you almost certainly killed it with 220v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear why you would or if you did connect 220V directly to the iron or if it was to the transformer base unit when debugging.

Connecting 220VAC directly to the iron would ruin it. Also the connections, internal wiring and Magnastat switch is not rated for that voltage so sparks and fire are likely.

Even 32VAC will cause it to heat very rapidly, possibly exceeding the current and certainly exceeding the element temperature every time before the Magnastat has time to switch open.

Also if you are trying to run it with 24 to 32 V DC you will ruin the Magnastat contacts very soon, those switches are rated for 55VA loads at 25V AC and are not overdesigned.

Answer (score 2):

A 50W at 24V would be (**very** briefly) 5kW at 220V. The heaters are fairly expensive.

If you were fortunate enough to not have a tip stuck in there the magswitch should have been open and your heater could have survived. Otherwise I'm afraid you have ruined it.